# Angular2 - Why does JsonPipe surround model properties with quotes?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template

In Angular 2, I have a component that subscribes to a service that returns a model and then displays the model property in a <textarea> using JsonPipe. For some reason the displayed property is surrounded by quotes. Why is this happening?

My code (assume there is a service that correctly populates the model):

```
/* example.ts */
export interface Example {
    id: number;
    description: string;
}

/* example.component.ts */
export class ExampleComponent {
    public example: Object = Object;

    constructor(private _exampleService: ExampleService) {
        this._getExample();
    }

    private _getExample() {
        this._exampleService
            .getExample()
            .subscribe(example => this.example = <Example> example);
    }
}

/* example.template.ts */
<form>
    Description: <textarea>{{example.description | json}}</textarea>
</form>
```

This will render a <textarea> that looks like this:

```
              _______________________________
Description: | "this is the description"     |
              ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

There is no reason for quotes to surround the string. What is going on?

Comment: Try `asych` pipe instead of `json` pipe. Note that the `asych` pipe will `subscribe()` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From javascript documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
JSON.stringify('foo'); // '"foo"'
```

Now let's see angular2 source code:

```
@Pipe({name: 'json', pure: false})
@Injectable()
export class JsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string { return Json.stringify(value); }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/json_pipe.ts#L15

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/facade/src/lang.ts#L422